# Hover function in js spills over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up my page so that when the user hovers over an image a text shows up and some bubbles. There are eleven images of fish and each one has its own text and bubble. I made sure that there is no overlap in the divs containing the fish, but when one hovers over a particular image the text of some of the other images show up too. This is too distracting since the user would want to see one text at  a time. How can I solve this issue? Here is the link to the page: http://arabic001.com/colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious myself as to what the common solution is to this problem. 
When I run across this situation I use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin for jquery.

if you went this route, you would change each `.mouseOver(),.mouseOut()` to the following:

### from this

```
          $('#fishBlue').mouseover(function() {     
                $('#bubblesBlue').toggle('slow');
                $('#textBlue').toggle('slow');
            });

            $('#fishBlue').mouseout(function() {                
                $('#bubblesBlue').hide('slow');
                $('#textBlue').toggle('slow');
            });
```

### to this

```
$('#fishBlue').hoverIntent(function() {
                $('#bubblesBlue').toggle('slow');
                $('#textBlue').toggle('slow');
            });
}, function() {
                $('#bubblesBlue').hide('slow');
                $('#textBlue').toggle('slow')
});
```

#### *note*

that the hoverIntent plugin requires at least jquery 1.5.1

#### other tip

I would abstract things a bit more, why rewrite the same thing for each fish.

perhaps use classes

```
$('.fish').hoverIntent(function() {
                $(this).next('.bubble').toggle('slow');
                $(this).next('.text').toggle('slow');
            });
}, function() {
                $(this).next('.bubble').hide('slow');
                $(this).next('.text').toggle('slow')
});
```

Comment: I looked at my index file and it says that I have JS 1.4. What do I do to make it 1.5.1?

Comment: seeing how you are using jquery from google just change the version number -- check out the available versions: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: If I want to use classes for the hover function like matchew has recommended, do I need to make any changes in the html index file?